# Pass URL parameter to php file through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to pass URL along with all parameters through .htaccess to get in other php file. For example:

URL : `abc.com/article/test1/test2/test3/?param1=1&param=2`

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?q=$1 [NC]

  </IfModule>
```

router.php

```
echo $_GET['q'];
```

I am getting output as `article/test1/test2/test3/`

But i need output as `article/test1/test2/test3/?param1=1&param=2`

Comment: Why do you want it like that and not available via `$_GET['param1']` for example?

Comment: QSA might be more helpful to you, but who knows.

Comment: Using `QSA` you will get query string as: `q=article/test1/test2/test3/&param1=1&param=2` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `QSA` worked for me. I added `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]`  and i am able to get all the parameters. Thank you very much for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rule line to

```
RewriteRule .* router.php [END]
```

All the info you're looking for is right there, in PHP, in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which you can parse however you want.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your rewrite rule is not preserving the parameters, you need to add `[R=302,L]` to your rule.